# Access with ajax delivered data on a server side php-script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

Okay my problem is the following:

I am trying to access a variable I defined with javascript in my executing php-script.

```
// CLIENT SIDE CODE

function deleteEntry() {
      var action = '_includes/deleteEntry.php';
      var method = 'post';
      var data = '2';

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data

    }).done(function(data){
        $('.main').empty();
        $('.main').append(data);
    });

};
```

Now I want to make use of my data in a php-script (deleteEntry.php)

```
// SERVER SIDE CODE

<?php
    // VERBINDUNG //
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aufgabenplaner');
    // if (!$connection){
    //     die('Verbindung nicht möglich : ' . mysql_error());
    // }

    // SQL-ABFRAGE //
    $query = "DELETE FROM aufgaben WHERE job_nr =" ."DATA GOES HERE!!!";
    $result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

    include 'main-content.php';
?>
```

Where it says "DATA GOES HERE!!!" I want to make use of the data value, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you pass a JSON object as your POST

```
$.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: 'post', //put your declaration here for readability
    data: {'var' : 2}
})
```

Then you would use `$_POST['var']` in your PHP to get the value

Comment: thanks buddy. that worked. I am sorry, this i probably some of the php-basics, but I am new to backend devoloping so... thanks a lot:)!

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare `data` object so it has key - value pairs. This way you'll be able to access data in your PHP script. JavaScript:

```
function deleteEntry() {
      var action = '_includes/deleteEntry.php';
      var method = 'post';
      var data =  { number: '2'};

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: method,
        data: data

    }).done(function(data){
        $('.main').empty();
        $('.main').append(data);
    });

};
```

PHP:

```
// SERVER SIDE CODE

<?php
    // VERBINDUNG //
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aufgabenplaner');
    // if (!$connection){
    //     die('Verbindung nicht möglich : ' . mysql_error());
    // }

    // SQL-ABFRAGE //
    $number = (int)$_POST['number']; // make sure it's no malicious input from user
    $query = "DELETE FROM `aufgaben` WHERE `job_nr` = '" . $number . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

    include 'main-content.php';
?>
```

Comment: yeah thank you as well! That worked. And dont worry, there won't be malicious input from user since i only want to deliver an id of  what has been clicked (in this case an entry of a task tool i am working on), so i can delete only the clicked entry;)